# Fetching data from Object -Scenario

Tags: lookup

1. I have an object **Client** with lookup to **Account**.
2. I have another object **Propose** with lookup to **Account**.
3. I have another object **Order** with lookup to **Client**.

I want to fetch data from **Order** object where `fieldvalue==X` in object **Propose** and an `fieldvalue=Y` in object **Client**.

How can this be achieved?

Answer (score 0):

This essentially appears to be a query on Order object(as you mentioned : "fetch data from Order object") - but it is not due to complicated conditions on the query which cannot be satisfoed by the WHERE clause of a SOQL.

An "Order" is related to one "Client" (So, "fieldvalue=Y in object Client") can be taken care of in a SOQL WHERE clause. "Client" and "Propose" both a lookup to account, which in this case acts as a junction object between client and propose, so the relationship between "client" and "propose" is many to many i.e. one client record can be related to many propose records and vice versa. Hence, one order can be related to multiple propose and vice versa. So, when you say - fieldvalue==X in object Propose , the question to ponder is "which propose record?".

To actually meet a criterion like this you could do the following:

1. Query on "Account" and this query has two child queries on "propose" and "client" querying based on the respective filter conditions.

   [SELECT id,(SELECT id FROM ProposeChildRelName WHERE field1 = X),(SELECT id FROM ClientChildRelName WHERE field2 = Y) FROM Account]
2. Iterate through this queries list of accounts and check if both the child related lists are not null. If then, add all the children "Client IDs" to a set of IDs.
3. Query out all the "Order" records whose parent is in the above set of client IDs.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thank you Stygon for the detailed answer . I will try this out and update.